# php-скрипт преждевременно перестает сам себя вызывать

Tags: php, get

Скрипт, который представлен ниже не совершает всех 50-ти шагов. Он отрабатывает только 43 шага максимум у меня, если запускать с первого шага, и полностью, если запускать после 10-го шага. Не могу понять, почему так происходит. Если кто может подсказать, что не так в этой реализации, ну, или как реализовать работающий (потенциально бесконечный) рекурсивный вызов скриптом самого себя, пожалуйста, не проходите мимо.

(уровень знаний php - ноль, учу для удовольствия, но пока только раздражение)

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['step'])) {
    $step = $_GET['step'];
    if ($step <= 50) {
      //file_put_contents("$step.log", $step);
        $step++;
        sleep(1);
        file_get_contents("https://myhost.domain/get.php?step=$step");
        exit();
    } else {
      //file_put_contents('end.log', $step);
    }
} else {
    //file_put_contents('end.log', "no steps");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: а что вы называете шагами? у вас там нету циклов

Comment: @splash58 get-запрос к самому себе, очевидно

Comment: зачем вам это вообще? `sleep` уберите, если выполнится, то отпадывает по таймлимиту.

Comment: Если решили изучать язык - изучайте его системно. Возьмите книгу, где пошагово и с примерами разжевываются некие конкретные аспекты языка, его применения. Судя по Вашему сообщению, у Вас "0" не только по уровню языка, но и по уровню знания реализации вэб-запросов, и по уровню понимания его применимости. Системность в изучении языка поможет Вам снять раздражение от непонимания применимости языка, даст знание о смежных технологиях, без которых применение PHP малопродуктивно - вэб-серверах, базах данных, HTML, CSS и т.д. А также снимет вопрос "потенциально бесконечного рекурсивного вызова".

Comment: Спасибо, что не прошли мимо. Жаль, что не помогло. SLEEP - это просто то место, где будет нагрузка. Если его убрать ничего не меняется... Вообще ничего, кроме скорости выполнения 43-х шагов (запросов).
Про системность изучения языка я в курсе, просто, это тоже сегодня не решает поставленной задачи. Извините за потраченное Ваше время.

Comment: Скорее всего, достигается ограничение по количеству запущенных процессов. Или по памяти. Зависит от сервера, где это выполняется. Можно увеличить лимиты, но бесконечной вложенности не получится.